# Executing shell script containing java -jar Runtime.exec(), which java will it take, OS level or application level

Tags: java, performance, shell, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to execute a java jar from my jmeter tests via beanshell.

The approach I followed is to create a shell script, execute it through beanshell using Runtime.exec() function.

**The question I have is whether execution of this shell script will take java from instance/host/OS level or it will be executed as part of current java that the application is using.**

There could be open questions for which I want to provide an answer to before time:

1. I have a maven project, in which I specify java.
2. The build runs the jmeter script which has beanshell executing the jar file.
3. I also do some processing with the output of the jar execution(write specific output to another file, hence I wrote the shell script).
4. I use this specific output, and use it to add to my request in jmeter before querying.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It will not re-use the current JVM, if that's what you're asking about. It will use whichever `java` command is encountered first on the applicable `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way, both.

The shell script will be executed as part of your Java program, but it will be executed using the system's default Java executable unless you've specified a Java executable in the `exec()` method call.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but would appreciate a sample of what you mean by "unless you've specified a Java executable in the exec() method call."

Comment: An example would be `Runtime.exec("/path/to/java/executable script.sh");` in which the path to a specific Java executable is specified as the first "argument" in the method call ("/path/to/java/executable").

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you run your application. If you just use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ....");
```

The [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) instance will look for `java` executable which is available in your OS [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). If there will no be `java` executable in the PATH - the call will fail.

---

Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting so consider migrating to Groovy on next available opportunity. For instance you can kick off the process and get the output as simple as:

```
String response = "your command".execute().text
```

Also instead of running your .jar in as separate process it might be better to add it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and call necessary functions directly from the Groovy code. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information.

Comment: A quick question, will JSR223 execute the command using java in application classpath or OS?

Comment: OS path, groovy provides only "syntax sugar" on top of JDK